# Finding 1-dimensional subsets of a finite 2-dimensional vector space.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let p be a prime number, and let F=Z<sub>p</sub> be the field of congruence classes of integers modulo p. let V=F<sup>2</sup> be the vector space of ordered pairs of elements of F. I have to find the number of 1 dimensional subspaces in V with p=7. I know that there should theoretically be 8=(7<sup>2</sup>-1)/(7-1), but I'm not sure why this should be. The only 1-dimensional subspaces of V are scalar multiples of single vectors but there are several vectors in V that have no nonzero scalar multiples in V (ex (3,4)) so when I do the math I get many more than 8 subspaces.

Comment: $(3, 4)$ generates a 1-dimensional subspace of $V$ just like any other non-zero element. That subspace contains $6 = 7 -1$ non-zero elements each of which generates the same subspace. That justifies the formula $(7^2 -1)/(7 - 1)$. You need to think again about your idea that $(3, 4)$ has no nonzero scalar multiples.

Comment: Of course $2(3,4)=(6,8)=(6,1)$ for $p=7$.

Comment: Oh I didn't realize that the mod function still applied there. I was just thinking of it as the set of all natural numbers less than p.